# jQuery Select box didn't show if no selected by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `select` boxes. One with list of Cities and the second one with Districts of Cities. When I chose (by click) the City from the first `select` box in the second box I see districts from selected City. That work perfectly, but when the City is selected automaticly by another script, the list of districts doesn't show - i have to manualy select the city from the list and then the list of districts appear.

Here is my script:

```
$.viewMap_get = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'Katowice' : $('#c1a, #c1b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Kraków' : $('#c2a, #c2b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Warszawa' : $('#c3a, #c3b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Wrocław' : $('#c4a, #c4b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Gdańsk' : $('#c5a, #c5b, #c6, #c7'),
}; 

$.each($.viewMap_get, function() { this.hide(); });
$('#get_city_district').hide();

$('#get_car').on('change', function() {
$('#return_city_district').show();
// hide all
$.each($.viewMap_get, function() { this.hide(); });
  $('#get_city_district').hide();
// show current
$.viewMap_get[$(this).val()].show();
  $('#get_city_district').show();

  var id = $.viewMap_get[$(this).val()].attr("id");   
  $('#'+id).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean a city is being set by a server-side script, or by another JavaScript script?

Comment: by JavaScript - compute function

Comment: Well then I can't imagine why it doesn't work, since that will still trigger the `change` event. Does that not fire? Put an alert in to find out. Can you set up a Fiddle?

Comment: i will try to put it in to Fiddle

Comment: My fidlle http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/W7NHK/62/

Answer (score 1):

Try this (See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bwWkK/1/) [in the end of js])

```
$('#get_car option:eq(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#get_car').trigger('change');
```

Comment: the scritp should display the same list under the city2 with krakow districts.

how it works. If the total day is less than 3 the value of the field City1 is transferred automatically into the City2. Under each of the cities should be displayed the list of Districts. however, if the value is copied from the City1 to city2 the list of Districts is not displayed